# Master Detail in Winform using LINQ

Tags: vb.net, linq, master-detail

I am looking for VB.NET code to join 2 tables to complete Master Detail for Winform using LINQ.

I found the following code snippet in C#. However VB.NET compiler does not like this syntax.

Please kindly provide me correct VB.NET code (I believe `INTO` is the error cause):

```
var matchingEmployees = 
     from dept in Departments
     join emp  in Employees on dept.DeptNo equals emp.DeptNo
     INTO AvailableEmployees
     SELECT NEW { department = dept, employees = AvailableEmployees };
```

REF: Article "[Creating Master Detail representation of data display in Winforms using LINQ (C#)](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31561/Creating-Master-Detail-representation-of-data-disp)" from Code Project

Answer (score 0):

I believe that should be a `Group Join` in VB.NET :

```
Dim matchingEmployees = 
        From dept In Departments _
        Group Join emp In Employees On dept.DeptNo Equals emp.DeptNo _
        Into AvailableEmployees = Group _
        Select New With {.department = dept, .employees = AvailableEmployees}
```

References :

- About group join : [MSDN : join clause (c#)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311040.aspx)
- Group join syntax in VB.NET : [Using LINQ Group Joins in VB.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7811417/using-linq-group-joins-in-vb-net)